# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) with maybe broken language-pack-en

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

I tried to upgrade apt on ubuntu 18.04 and got this Error:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3
  libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-writer
  linux-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04
  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 openjdk-11-jdk openjdk-11-jdk-headless
  openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless python3-uno
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/250 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package language-pack-en (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-en-base:
 language-pack-en-base depends on language-pack-en (>= 1:18.04+20180712); however:
  Package language-pack-en is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-en-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-gnome-en:
 language-pack-gnome-en depends on language-pack-en; however:
  Package language-pack-en is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-gnome-en (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-gnome-en-base:
 language-pack-gnome-en-base depends on language-pack-gnome-en (>= 1:18.04+20180712); however:
  Package language-pack-gnome-en is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-gnome-en-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 language-pack-en
 language-pack-en-base
 language-pack-gnome-en
 language-pack-gnome-en-base
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.2.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have also tested all of  [this page's](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1)  methods but the problem still exists...
These are the outputs of those methods :
1- using **sudo dpkg --configure -a**

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-en-base:
 language-pack-en-base depends on language-pack-en (>= 1:18.04+20180712); however:
  Package language-pack-en is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-en-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-gnome-en:
 language-pack-gnome-en depends on language-pack-en; however:
  Package language-pack-en is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-gnome-en (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-gnome-en-base:
 language-pack-gnome-en-base depends on language-pack-gnome-en (>= 1:18.04+20180712); however:
  Package language-pack-gnome-en is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-gnome-en-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 language-pack-en-base
 language-pack-gnome-en
 language-pack-gnome-en-base
```

2- using **sudo apt-get install –f**

```
$ sudo apt-get install –f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package –f
```

3- using **sudo apt-get remove ––purge language-pack-en**

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ––purge language-pack-en
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ––purge
```

4- using **sudo apt-get autoremove**

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/250 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package language-pack-en (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-en-base:
 language-pack-en-base depends on language-pack-en (>= 1:18.04+20180712); however:
  Package language-pack-en is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-en-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-gnome-en:
 language-pack-gnome-en depends on language-pack-en; however:
  Package language-pack-en is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-gnome-en (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-gnome-en-base:
 language-pack-gnome-en-base depends on language-pack-gnome-en (>= 1:18.04+20180712); however:
  Package language-pack-gnome-en is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-gnome-en-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 language-pack-en
 language-pack-en-base
 language-pack-gnome-en
 language-pack-gnome-en-base
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.2.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: What have you used as '-' character?   it should be a hyphen but it doesn't copy/paste as one, which matches your messages.

Comment: Yeah,  you're right... I checked all the methods again( with the correct form) and the output was like the first method's output  :((